# Another way instead Select Case

Tags: sql, t-sql

Is there any way instead using Case statement in t-sql?
for example :

```
select case day
       when 0
       then 'sun'
       when 1
       then 'mon' ...
       else 'sat'
       end as dayName
from   table
```

Now I want to know a better way than "case statement" like struct in C# or simple functions or dictionary! you can send a key and use the value member instead select case.

Comment: For this example there is http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395%28v=sql.105%29.aspx.

Comment: As an alternative to the bult-in function you can use a second table with the names you want and then join your tables.

Comment: If you have a date, use `datename()`.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about the general construct of `KEY-VALUE` pairs - and if there is an analog for them in SQL. The answer is yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly... then yes, there are other ways.
Whether they are better or not depends largely on context!

A dictionary is a collection with an index of sorts. In this example, `#DayTable` plays that roles.

If you are asking about conditional programming constructs, then within a `SELECT` statement, I think the answer is no, prior to SQL Server 2012 which has `IIF()` [BOL Ref](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx)

This differs somewhat to the `IF` controlling logic flow - outside of a `SELECT` statement.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DayTable')IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DayTable
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ArbEvent')IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ArbEvent

CREATE TABLE #DayTable (DayID INT, DayTextName VARCHAR(30))
INSERT INTO #DayTable
(DayID, DayTextName)
VALUES
(1, 'Monday'), (2, 'Tuesday'), (3, 'Wednseday'), (4, 'Thursday'), (5, 'Friday'), (6, 'Saturday'), (7, 'Sunday')

CREATE TABLE #ArbEvent (EventName VARCHAR(30), DayID INT)
INSERT INTO #ArbEvent
(EventName, DayID)
VALUES
('John''s Birthday', 1), ('Susan''s Funeral', 2), ('Pick Jessica up', 6)

SELECT   AE.EventName
        ,AE.DayID
        ,DT.DayTextName 
FROM #ArbEvent  AE
JOIN #DayTable  DT  ON AE.DayID = DT.DayID
```

Comment: #TableName is a temporary table and for each request it should be make. other way I want to avoid create another table to keeping values and keys. We have many items in Sql server such as functions or user types and ... . I'm looking for a very new method, but your method is awesome.

Comment: If you could help by posting more about exactly what you need to achieve, people here will show you methods for accomplishing your goal.

Comment: For the beginning, where should I keep your code? In a view or a stored procedure or use it query's body? We have dictionary in C# that it has a key column and a value column. So we have tables in Sql with many columns. Here I say, Is there a Data Type or function that we declare our keys and values there and use them in other places instead of tables for keeping values.

Comment: You could use any of the methods you've described. Depending on the situation, I would probably use a table.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for another way.  Here is another way:

```
select left(datename(dw, dateadd(day, [day], '2014-01-25')), 3)
```

The constant `'2014-01-25'` is simply your favorite Saturday.

I'm not advocating using this.  I think the `case` statement is much clearer in intention.

Comment: datename(month)?  Shouldn't that be datename(dw)?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way...

```
declare @day int
set @day = 1
select SUBSTRING('sunmontuewedthufrisat',(@day*3)+1,3) as dayName
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, simply use a table or inline view.

```
select dayname
from   table t
join   ( select 1 nr
         ,      'mon' dayname
         union
         select 2
         ,      'tue'
       ) v
on     t.day = v.nr
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we have to declare a scalar-valued function and use it in the query like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fcDayName
(
   @DayNo tinyint
)
RETURNS nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE @day nvarchar(20)

-- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
set @day = (SELECT case @DayNo when 1 then 'Mon' when 2 then 'Tue' when 3 then 'Wed' ... end as d)

-- Return the result of the function
RETURN @day
```

END

And use it:

```
 Select Code, dbo.fcDayName(Day) AS Day, S_Bank From Table
```